# Change OneDrive display name on Windows 11

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, onedrive

**For some context**: I am a transgender university student. My university provides me with a lot of useful OneDrive storage space. However, since I haven't been able to update my legal name (and my university won't let me modify the name associated to my institutional account), this means my OneDrive is associated to my deadname.

What makes this particularly problematic is that this shows up on Windows Explorer no matter what I do. This folder is right above the Quick Access tab, meaning I can't unpin it, and Windows Explorer won't let me rename it either.

[image: OneDrive folder screenshot]

**Question**: Is there a way to change the display name of this folder? Or if that's not possible, is there a way to unpin the folder permanently?

I'm not beyond using registry hacks or startup scripts if necessary. This has been bothering me for far too long at this point. I'm using Windows 11.

Comment: On my own Windows 11 machines, the name is the name from my Microsoft Account. I imagine deadname is from the School Account, so you likely need to enlist their help. It may mean an new User Profile for your computer.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that my school hasn't let me update my name on said school account.

Comment: I am not sure there is much you can do. Trying to hack the name on the Windows Account (School Account) could easily lead to bigger issues. Maybe escalate within your school as many schools are sensitive to individuals.

Comment: That sucks, I'll keep trying on that front then.

Comment: I don't know if this will work. However, check out this registry key: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ServicesManagerCache\Identities\0f664cab02fe217f_LiveId\WLINBOX_SKYDRIVE_0f664cab02fe217f_97`. The `0f664...` may be different on your system. There are multiple string names such as `ConnectionDisplayName` and `ConnectionUriDocumentsDisplayName` that appear to be the friendly name. Try changing them and rebooting. (I can't currently reboot my system to see if it works).

Comment: This problem can only be resolved through your school. I am shocked a University does not have a process to update the legal name of a student.  **I knew a handful of students who's name changed before graduation, none of them, ever had a problem updating their legal name with the school or the state.**

Comment: The problem is that this isn't my legal name yet. Since I study in a different state than where I was born, it's not been possible for me to go through the legal procedure.

Comment: @Brian I changed the fields and rebooted my computer. The fields don't seem to be overridden to their defaults on reboot. However, the Windows Explorer folder name persists.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. That was the closest thing I could find that might possibly have worked. I think I am throwing my hat in the basket with the others that this needs to be a change by your institution. Hopefully someone in their IT department will come through for you.

Comment: Does this work, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/716992/onedrive-and-org-name-change see answer Himansukh Chauha

Comment: Talk to your school. They can and should be able to make the change. They have ultimate control over their accounts.